# knowing what object to get() from an arrayList

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

This isn't another how do I get an object from a collection.  I have a predicament that is troubling me. I will do my best to explain the problem clearly.

I am working on a game, this game revolves around players looking after pets. I have decided it would be appropriate to have an arrayList of a players pets.  (so an ArrayList  allPets etc... in the players class)

My problem is when a player wants to do something with his/hers pets e.g. feed it how can I know exactly which index to use in the get method of the arrayList so I feed the correct pet?

This may be a simple problem but its confusing me, I am in the process of rigging up all the methods between player and pet but it dawned on me how will I actually know which pet object has been clicked. At the moment I have simply been passing in a pet object which I created for the purpose of testing the methods. That's not going to cut it when It comes to actual pet objects on the screen...

Any insight would be much appreciated!!

Comment: It seems more like the `Pet`(s) should be a field of `Player`.

Comment: You mean player? it is , Arraylist <pet> allPets ....etc is in the player class.

Comment: Why not store them in a `Map` instead of an `ArrayList` so you can grab the correct one by some key like name or id?

Comment: @whiteElephant  Yep.  That is what I meant.  So why can you not tell which `Player` it is?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Why the down vote? A Map  - Im new to java and haven't heard of this. I will check it out. It still seems to me that Im stuck with the problem of knowing the actual name or id? where would these be stored?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post some of your code, specifically the UI where you're setting up the list of pets and the event handling for selecting a pet.

Comment: aw shame question rejected. Thought it might have been clear enough without code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the Pet objects, a unique primary key.  An integer ID field is popular, extremely efficient & sufficient to handle all but the largest transaction volumes.

Then, you can maintain a Map and efficiently get Pets by ID. This pattern can be used throughout your model.

With commercial applications backed by a SQL database, the similar pattern is used as well -- but retrieval is done via Hibernate.

Simple example:

```
public class Player {
    protected List<Pet>        petList = new ArrayList();
    protected Map<Integer,Pet> petMap =  new HashMap();

    public List<Pet> getPets() {return petList;}
    public Pet getPetById (int id) {return petMap.get( id);}
    public void addPet (Pet pet) {
        petList.add( pet);
        petMap.put( pet.getId(), pet);
    }
}

public class Pet {
    protected int id;
    // Id;
    public int getId() {return id;}

    // create;  static factory.
    //
    public static Pet createPet() {
        Pet pet = new Pet();
        pet.id = KeyAllocator.alloc("pet");
        return pet;
    }
}
```

Hint:  you can use LinkedHashMap to retain order of the Pets, without having to keep a List as well;  but it changes getPets() return-type from List to Collection, which is a bit less nice.

KeyAllocator.alloc() enables you to re-use the allocation logic;  basically it should start at 1 and increment inside a 'synchronized' block. (Avoid 0, since if you ever store your data with a persistence layer, 0 tends to mean 'new'.)

Comment: Very elegantly explained.  I hesitate to recommend Hibernate or ORM to someone who is "new to Java" ... although, admittedly, I'm not sure that lower level JDBC calls are a "simpler" paradigm either.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm in the process of testing it out. Having issues with the KeyAllocator though , it cannot be resolved ?

Comment: KeyAllocator is for you to write;  at it's simplest it could allocate from a single counter, regardless of the 'sequence' parameter. But if you want to be nice about it, you can number Player, Pets, Treasures etc independently.

Comment: Hey Thomas W,  don't know if you will get this message but if you do I am just wondering if you explain why createPet should be static? Cheers

Comment: I like to distinguish 'loadPet' from 'createPet' very clearly, in my database applications, since the behaviour is quite different.  Constructors can't be named, so to make the semantics clear & explicit (which is basic good coding practice) I use static functions, which can be named.

Comment: I guess its due to lack of experience but I don't follow you there. If you could explain in more detail I'd appreciate it? a bit of a hassle a know but I am keen to learn. Are you referring to the constructor as the ability to loadPet ?

Comment: In your case, you're doing `createPet()`. But as soon as you want to **store your data**, you'll need `loadPet( int id)` and similar methods. These should be static. Running both 'load' and 'create' thru constructors becomes very unclear, and is a common 'smell' in legacy applications I've worked on.

Comment: I have much to learn, one last thing if you have the time/patients - do you think createPe() should be in the pet class or in a main class where the setup method will be? Thanks for your help appreciate it.

Comment: Pet class. You'd probably have similar methods for Player, Treasure, etc etc & they may as well be placed with their classes.